# CDATA section gets HTML encoded in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cdata

I am using a spring MVC to return a response entity which will produce MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE. I am returning one of the xml attributes in a CData section so that it isn't parsed by the xml parser.
For eg : . the < , > and & get html encoded as >, < and & . I want the value to be returned without HTML encoding.
Could any one please help me on solving this?